# How to open a mp4 local file using default application - AIR?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, jquery-animate, external, local

I've been trying to open a local video (mp4) as an AIR application using an android tablet, no success.

I've tryed to use URL adress but did not work as well.

I want to create a button that when pressed will open a internal .mp4 video using default android application to run this video. LIke opening a external webpage, but with video.

the video is located: /storage/extSdCard/Dealer Manager/10_VIDEOS/01_VIDEOS_COLHEDORA/Demonstração Grupo Biosev/video02.mp4

If someone could help me with that I would be very grateful.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [file.openWithDefaultApplication()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#openWithDefaultApplication%28%29)? It's AIR-only but might do exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm having trouble to construct the code. Everything I have tried did not work. Can you help me with the code? I'm not doing it right

Comment: I'm close to this code:
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.net.FileFilter;

var file:File = File.documentsDirectory; 
var mp3Filter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("MP3 Files", "*.mp3"); 
file.browseForOpen("Open", [mp3Filter]); 
file.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, fileSelected); 
 
function fileSelected(e:Event):void 
{ 
    file.openWithDefaultApplication(); 
}

do you know how to insert a specific path and open mp4 file format?